# How to estimate exposure in Roentgens/hr from 99m Tc on a given distance?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I tried to find out how to calc it myself, but seems it's not something very straigthforward... I hope it's not a bad question, sorry if it is!

So, this is known:

- It's <sup>99m</sup>Tc
- Let's assume it's point source
- It's the gamma radiation
- A = quantity is 50 MBq
- E = photon energy is 140 keV
- R = distance is 10 cm

I think I also need radiation intensity (photon yield) for <sup>99m</sup>Tc before we go further - where this can be found?

After I know the photon yield value (y), I think I can find amount of energy coming per seconds through a unit of area on the given distance:

**ψ = AyE/4πr<sup>2</sup> = y * 50*10<sup>6</sup> * 140<sup>3</sup> / (4 * 3.1416 * 10<sup>2</sup>) = y *   5,570 MeV/cm<sup>2</sup>/s**

Is this right so far?
 But anyway even if "y" is known, this is where I stop...

**How this amount translates then into the Roentgens/hr??** I'm really puzzled by how Roentgen unit is defined - conversion from known eV does not seem to be very straighthforward.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use Google to look up the specific gamma ray constant for Tc-99m

Comment: Thanks @imabug!! This really helps

Comment: To continue on your original track, another tidbit that might be helpful is that the Roentgen is the amount of ionization produced per kg, and is only defined for air.  1 R = 1 C/kg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @imabug suggested, it's really much simpler than I tried, with all the intermediate calculations already wrapped into well-known constants. Details are here, it even contains the exposure rate constant for the 99mTc:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_exposure#Exposure_rate_constant

For 50MBq, it's this:

- 50Mbq = 1.35mCi
- Exposure rate constant for <sup>99m</sup>Tc, Г =
  0.720

So exposure at 10 cm is = 0.72 * 1.35 / 10<sup>2</sup> ~= 0.009730 R/h = 9.73 mR/h